# Have you ever interfaced a MAX44009 sensor with a uC?

Tags: c, sensors, i2c, mikroc, dspic

I recently tried to program, using the free download version of MikroC for dsPIC IDE, a MAX44009 sensor to interface with PIC24FJ64GB002 microcontroller. The lux result of the sensor should be displayed on an LCD. The code compiles without failure, but it's not working. When I view the SDA and SCL lines using an oscilloscope, they are always held high. But if I convert:

float luminance --> int luminance

and

FloatToStr (luminance, lux) --> IntToString (luminance, lux)

then the code is loaded onto the embedded device, and the oscilloscope shows that the I2C communication is taking place, but the value the LCD displays does not give any valuable data. The lux display is -17204 and it never changes.

I tried to display "exponent" on the LCD and it displayed: -17204
I tried to display "mantissa" on the LCD and it displayed: 255

When I tried to debug the code, when luminence is declared as a float, I get an error: "Simulation Error: PC out of scope [0x0011F0]"
When I change from float to int; I can debug the code, but the value output on the LCD is useless.

```
//LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at LATB2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at LATB3_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at LATB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at LATB7_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at LATB13_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at LATB14_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB7_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB13_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB14_bit;
//End LCD Module connections

//Global Constants
char txt1[] = "LUX:";
char txt2[] = "check";
//End Global Constants


// Global var.
unsigned int buff[2];
//unsigned char b1Index;
int mantissa;
int exponent;
float luminance;
char lux[16];
//end of Global variable declaration

//Function declaration
void MAX44009_getvalue();
//end of function declaration

void main(){
AD1PCFG = 0xffff;                        //Configure AN pins as digital 
I/O
Delay_ms(500);
I2C1_Init(100000);                       //Initialize I2C communication 
on SDA1 and SCL1
I2C1_Start();                  //Wake-up I2C components
I2C1_Write(0x96);              //Address MAX44009 lux sensor 
specifically, and prepare for write command
I2C1_Write(0x02);              //Address specific register 02 (interupt 
register) for MAX44009
I2C1_Write(0x40);              //Continuous mode, 100ms integration time
I2C1_Stop();                   //issue I2C stop signal
Delay_ms(300);                 //Because Arduino said so....

Lcd_Init();                              //Initialize LCD
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);                     //Clear LCD
Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);                //Cursor Off

/*Delay_ms(1000);
Lcd_Out(2,1,txt2);
Delay_ms(1000);*/

while (1){
    MAX44009_getvalue();
    exponent = (buff[0] & 0xF0) >> 4;
    mantissa = ((buff[0] & 0x0F ) << 4) | (buff[1] & 0x0F);
    luminance = pow(2, exponent)*mantissa*0.045;

    FloatToStr(luminance, lux);

    Lcd_Out(1,1,txt1);
    Lcd_Out(2,1,lux);
    Delay_ms(500);
}
}

void MAX44009_getvalue(){

I2C1_Start();
I2C1_Write(0x96);
I2C1_Write(0x03);             //MAX44009 LUX High-Byte Register 0x03
I2C1_Restart();
I2C1_Write(0x97);

buff[0] = I2C1_Read(0);

I2C1_Restart();

I2C1_Write(0x96);
I2C1_Write(0x04);              //MAX44009 LUX Low-Byte Register 0x04
I2C1_Restart();
I2C1_Write(0x97);

buff[1] = I2C1_Read(0);

I2C1_Stop();
}
```

Expected Results: Working MAX44009 lux sensor code, displaying lux values on an LCD

Simulation Error: PC out of scope [0x0011F0]

Comment: it may be stupid but have you included `math.h` ?

Comment: Definitely not a stupid question. Yes I have included the math library in MikroC - thanks for the comment.

Comment: `FloatToStr(luminance, lux);` can you show us this code?

Comment: I can't show you exactly what the code is, as it is part of the mikroC library "Conversions Library", but I can tell you what the "Help" file says with regards to the function? Not sure if it will help at all, but:

Comment: FloatToStr: Prototype -  unsigned char FloatToStr(float fnum, unsigned char*str);

Comment: Description - Converts a floating point number to a string. The output string is left justified and null terminated after the last digit.

Comment: Parameters - fnum: floating point number to be converted, str: destination string

Comment: Returns: 3 if the input number is NaN, 2 if the input number is -INF, 1 if the input number is +INF, 0 if the conversion was successful

Comment: Requires - Destination string should be at least 14 characters in length

Comment: Example:   float ff1 = -374.2; float ff2 = 123.45678; float ff3 = 0.000001234; char txt[15];

Comment: FloatToStr(ff1, txt);      // txt is "-374.2"

Comment: FloatToStr(ff2, txt);   // txt is "123.4567"

Comment: please [edit] your question instead of adding a million comments. It'll be much clearer.

Comment: FloatToStr(ff3, txt);    // txt is "1.234e-6"

Comment: Sorry - It's done now though, that's what the help file says.

Comment: see my comment above :)